# does the wife have priority in separating challah?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, separating-challah

is it true that the wife has priority in separating challah (as it seems from Jewish articles:

[chabad.org](http://chabad.org/2689640)

> While both men and women are obligated in these fundamental mitzvot, **the Jewish woman has been given precedence and carries the authority in ensuring their proper fulfillment**

[Aish.com](http://aish.com/sh/t/rai/48970616.html)

> Today too, women are given **precedence** in performing this mitzvah)?

if yes, what is the source for this?

form Y"D [328.3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.328.3) it seems the priority goes to the owner of dough (which seems in most cases to be the husband)

Answer (score 1):

Since they were the ones taking care of the needs of the house, there were certain tasks that fell under their care.

See the mishna in [Shabbos Chapter 2:](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Shabbat.2.6?with=Bartenura&lang=bi)

> עַל שָׁלשׁ עֲבֵרוֹת נָשִׁים מֵתוֹת בִּשְׁעַת לֵדָתָן, עַל שֶׁאֵינָן זְהִירוֹת בַּנִּדָּה וּבַחַלָּה וּבְהַדְלָקַת הַנֵּר:
>
> Women die in childbirth for three transgressions: If they are not careful with [the laws] of menstruation; and if they are not careful [to separate some] dough [when baking to give to the priest]; and if they are not careful with the lighting of the [Shabbat] lamp.

Bartenura explains:

> Regarding Challah and lighting Shabbat candles-Because these are among the needs of a household, and she is found at home, and therefore she is bound to them.

Comment: +1 but your sources seem to be regarding not doing it, but maybe this is only in a case when the husband asked her to do it, how do we know she has precedence? (by candles we know shulchan aruch harav 263.5 http://www.chabad.org/3447046/#footnoteRef27a3447046 )

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Shabbat.2.7?with=all&lang=bi From the very next mishna we see that the the husband reminds her about these duties to make sure she did them. He doesn't come home and do them himself.

Comment: is this you hidush or there are respected sources saying so?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are calling this a chidush on my part. I see a Bartenura which I guess we can call a chidush, but it seems logical. It seems to be along the lines mitzvah haba liyadcha, and mitzvah hamutal alav etc.

Comment: why by candles it is explained clearly (my source above (footnote 28 there says the obligation is the husbands but because of specific reasons preference is given do the wife) but by challah not so , I did not see a source that preference is given to her

Comment: There is a secondary kabalistic reason there about them putting out the light of the world (which is seemingly contradictory to the kabbalistic reason for them not to make borei meorei ha'eish on motzaei shabbos, but that is a different issue). However first the shulcha aruch harav brings the Rambam that this Bartenura stems from saying since they are the ones at home, they are supposed to light. Bartenura extends this to understand all three mitzvos.

Comment: he clearly says "woman is given precedence." his source is https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.263.6 who's source is the Bach, does someone say this concerning challa?

Comment: https://youtu.be/t5AzzDenarU

Comment: @Hazoriz at 1:25 the rebbe says the same as Bartenura. That was your point?

Comment: yep (15.15.15.15)

Comment: but it is still not simple that she has the priority, it is possible that only in practice they are the ones who do it most of the time

Comment: There is an expression in shas which still has a modern usage 'too many cooks spoil the food'. The explanation given there is that each cook will rely on the other one to spice and care for the food and in the end nobody will have taken care of it. Perhaps we can use that in order to understand why she is supposed to do it and not him specifically because of this. One of them has to have the responsibility, otherwise each one will rely on the other. She got the job since she runs the house.

Comment: priority will come into play when the husband demands the opportunity to do it, does he have the right to demand it, or not since it is her piority to do it, (as by shabbos candles)